# Status parameter in native EE Relationship field

Tags: relationships

I have a test tag where it's pulling data from a Native Relationship here:

http://staging.sewcratic.com/export/test

Here's the code under the "Data" header:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="patterns" limit="1" status="Open|Closed"}
    <p>{title}<p>
    <p>designer_label: {designer_label}{designer_label:entry_id}{/designer_label}</p>
    <p>design_label2: {design_label2 status="Open|Closed|Draft|Edited|Proofread"}{design_label2:title}{/design_label2}</p>
    <p>pattern_groups2: {pattern_groups2 backspace="1"}{pattern_groups2:entry_id},{/pattern_groups2}</p>
    <p>pattern_company2: {pattern_company2}{pattern_company2:entry_id}{/pattern_company2}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The fields {designer_label} and {pattern_groups2} are pulling, while {design_label2} does not. I've added all statuses to the {design_label2} tag, but does not seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does {design_label2:entry_id} print out?

Comment: Hi Anna, regretfully no - bit puzzled on this one.

Comment: What does your debugging output show? Is the query running and just returning no results?

Comment: Is it possible that the entries that {design_label2} would be pulling are expired?

Comment: Hey diemer -- I also put the show_expired parameter to no avail. It's gotta be something simple I'm missing but can't figure out what!

Comment: Hi Anna, looks like the query IS running, and looks like this: SELECT DISTINCT `L0`.`field_id` as L0_field, `L0`.`grid_field_id` as L0_grid_field_id, `L0`.`grid_col_id` as L0_grid_col_id, `L0`.`grid_row_id` as L0_grid_row_id, `L0`.`parent_id` AS L0_parent, `L0`.`child_id` as L0_id
FROM (`exp_relationships` as L0)
LEFT JOIN `exp_relationships` as L1 ON `L0`.`child_id` = `L1`.`parent_id` OR L1.parent_id = NULL
WHERE `L0`.`grid_field_id` =  0
AND `L0`.`parent_id` IN (44988) 
ORDER BY `L0`.`order` asc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried labeling the statuses without the initial caps?  I believe the default categories are open and closed not Open and Closed, is it possible that that is causing the issue for you?  Additionally if you are trying to show all entries except a certain one consider using not.  For example I have a status like `status="not closed|open|under_development"` in one of my relationship tags.

If you are trying to explicitly tell it to display all entries regardless of status, you can try `status="not nonexistant"` where nonexistant would be a status that has not been created so no entry will have it.

Comment: Ah -- it indeed was status. The "not nonexistent" trick is great (although there really should be an "all_status" value to do the same. Much appreciated UB!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity apparently is (well, *can be*) different between the parameters for channel entries and those for relationship fields. It's not a black-and-white difference, though, and is to do with one being governed by MySQL and the other being governed by PHP. See https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19913 for more info.

Comment: Good point Rick and totally agree. The seemingly inconsistent syntax is part of the issue. Thanks for the link!